# Transparent element (like a div-container) over embedded video

Tags: video, embed, opacity, transparent, wmode

I like to place an div-container over an embedded Video.
Something like this:

```
<style>
#container_above_video {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: red; /*that works*/
/*background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); that doesn't work*/
z-index: 99; /*has an effect at all?*/
</style>

  <div id="eineID" style="top: 0px; left: 91.8889px; width: 1182.22px; height: 665px;">
<embed id="vlcplugin" target="http://localhost:8097/mainmedia.ts?wmode=transparent" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" style="top: 0px; left: 91.8889px; width: 1182.22px; height: 665px;"></embed></div>

<div id="container_above_video">Some Content</div>
```

The problem is: I need an element, without background, or with transparent background, or with opacity on background/div - it doesn't work...

why?!

please help =)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution :

use `windowless="true"` in the embed parameters.

> windowless: (since VLC version 2.0.6) Draw the video on a window-less
>   (non-accelerated) surface and allow styling (CSS overlay, 3D
>   transformations, and much more). Default: false

More informations : https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/